# Is there a way to check loading status of dump mysql import?

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, docker, command-line-interface

I'm using the command below to import a backup.sql in mysql Docker container:

`cat backup.sql | docker exec -i CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=root DATABASE`

That works well, but sometimes the import takes a long time because of the size of the sql file dump. (~10 minutes or even more).

Is there any way I can check the status (loading percentage or something helpful) of the restore?

**TLDR:** Use the command template below replacing your settings.

`pv -pert <sql file> | docker exec -i <container> /usr/bin/mysql -u <user> --password=<password> <DATABASE>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I do:

```
pv -pert backup.sql | ...mysql command to restore...
```

The `pv` command shows a nice progress bar.

Example of restoring a 1.6GB sql file:

[image]

`pv` is not necessarily installed by default on your system, but it's commonly available in package repos. On my Mac, I installed it easily using `brew`.